# Como poner un valor predeterminado en el control ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net

Use el control ComboBox y agregue varios valores por medio de la ventana de propiedades en la parte de Item el cual te deja agregar en forma de colección.
La duda que tengo es cómo puedo hacer para que cuando inicie la aplicación, la primera opción del ComboBox sea el primer valor que está agregado en la colección.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Text = TextBox1.Text & " - " & ComboBox1.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: trata de agregar el codigo que estan realizando para que puedan ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te siguiero lo siguiente:

Coloca la propiedad [DropDownStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) del combobox como [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)
es realizar lo siguiente

```
miComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
miComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
```

con las dos líneas anterior (en orden de aparición) indicas al combobox que (digamos) restringa a los valores en `item` y que establezca como seleccionado el primer elemento (con -1 -menos uno- indicas ninguno).

Comment: Perdona la ignorancia, pero dónde/cómo debería agregar ese código? Ya que me estuve manejando usando la ventana de propiedades. El dropDownStyle lo pude cambiar desde ahi pero el SelectedIndex lo debería agregar a mano pero no se dónde, tal vez en el Form1.designer o en el Form1.vb mismo?.

Comment: El "SelectedIndex" debe estar en la propiedades (si mal no recuerdo); en caso que no, colocalo al final del código donde agregas elementos (no es en "String Collection Editor" de la imagen que incluyes); debe ser justo despues de la línea de código donde agregas al item; si esto no lo haces pues al momento de cargar tu formulario asi de sencillo y sin complicaciones. Éxito.

Comment: El problema es que por ahora no agregue codigo a mano, me maneje con la ventana de propiedades y los eventos. Es por eso que no se dónde debería crear/escribir el archivo para agregar esas lineas de código. Si agrego .SelectedIndex = 0 en el Form1.designer.vb, funciona bien, pero creo que debería de evitar escribir código ahi...

Answer (score 1):

Considero la respuesta de Roberto León Oramas bastante adecuada, pero frente a la inquietud del compañero Popplar de "y dónde coloco el código".

Pues puede ser en el Evento **Load** del **Formulario** en el que estas trabajando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, el evento Load del Form me permite hacer varias configuraciones de antemano, me viene de diez!
Si bien podía hacerlo desde el archivo Form1.designer en la parte donde se instancia el ComboBox, vi que no era nada recomendable cambiar algo en ese archivo por lo cual me entró la duda.
Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: No hay porque. Como bien lo dijiste el archivo de instancia del Combobox, el ".designer" puede almacenar también este tipo de acciones pero es recomendable hacerlo en el Load del formulario ya que es más fácil determinar dónde se hizo la asignación (el día de mañana, más adelante) y no tan "ocultamente".